# jQuery ajax call within KnockoutJS ViewModel not firing success callback

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following KnockoutJS ViewModel:

```
function UsersViewModel() {
  // data
  self.selectedUser = ko.observable();
  self.AddRolesFormIsVisible = ko.observable(false);

  // operations
  self.addRoleForSelectedUser = function() {
    self.selectedUser().roles.push(new Role({ Name: self.selectedRole().name() }));
    self.AddRolesFormIsVisible(false);
    $.post('http://localhost:23926/admin/acl/addusertorole', { username: self.selectedUser().name(), role: self.selectedRole().name() },
    function () {
        console.log('"UserRole" record created at db!');
    },
    'json');
  }
}
```

I have removed some properties and functions for brevity. I expect to see the `console.log()` result in Chrome Console, but I am not! And the weird bit is, the Ajax call does pass through, and my MVC controller is called and the role is actually removed from the database!

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you see any error when the ajax call is triggered?

Comment: nope, like I said, the call goes through, and my MVC controller action does what it is supposed to! Is this to do with `status codes`? What status code is returned by the MVC ActionController when it does its thing? and what does jQuery look for to determine that ajax was a success

Comment: I opened up Fiddler to monitor HTTP Requests, and can see that a **status code of 200** was returned by my MVC Controller. [Screenshot here](https://www.screencast.com/t/IkuK63mBDSAk).

Comment: Attach an "always" handler to your post function to see if there's a different error getting returned. $.post(...).always(function(data|jqXHR, textStatus, jqXHR|errorThrown){ check parameters here })